# Return both the largest and second largest dates, in separate columns, grouped by some factor

Tags: sql

Been struggling with this.   I need to return the largest date, grouped by some factor in 1 column, and the second largest date in a separate column.  I'm unable to use DATEADD function since there are gaps in the date.  The desired output will have three columns (the factor being grouped on, max date, 2nd largest date) and many rows.  Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic method is to use `row_number()` and aggregation.  Such as this:

```
select factor, max(date), min(date)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by factor order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by factor;
```

In the event of duplicates, this will return the same date twice.  If you want different dates, then use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: However, what if there is no grouping factor.  For example, I want to return all unique dates in col 1 and the prior date in col 2.  There are gaps in the dates.

Comment: If there's no grouping factor (or even if their is) and you just want the preceding records column value use the `lag` analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DB you may be able to use an analytic function like the `NTH_VALUE` function in Oracle:

```
select partition_cols, max(date1) date1, max(date2) date2
from (
  select partition_cols
       , NTH_VALUE(Date_Col, 1) over (partition by partition_cols order by ... 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) date1
       , NTH_VALUE(Date_Col, 2) over (partition by partition_cols order by ... 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) date2
    from your_data) t
group by partition_cols
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is similar to Gordon's but uses a pivot:

```
with t1 as (
select factor
     , row_number() over (partition by factor order by your_date) rn
     , your_date
  from Your_Data
)
select * from t1 pivot (max(your_date) for rn in (1, 2)) x
```